# Cannot change ImageView color on API 16

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an imageview which have to change it's color dynamically, to change color im using

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(229, 0, 0),PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN);
```

This works on API 21+ but not on older API 16, how can I make imageview to change it color in older api's too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this was really good solution for my case!
I've added two values into xml drawable

```
<color name="color_active">#E50000</color>
<color name="color_deactive">#12AD2A</color>

imageView.setImageResource(R.color.color_active);
imageView.setImageResource(R.color.color_deactive);
```